# Temporary table in multithread

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, temp-tables

I have a multithread application.

Each thread executes store procedures in which I create a local temporary table.
The name of the temporary table is the same :  `#TempTable`

I have a conflict between thread when they manipulate this `#TempTable`

How can I make a `#TempTable` for each thread with the same name ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to ensure each thread is running in a different connection from the connectio npool (so it is in a different session).

Temp tables are only visible in their own session.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx):

> Local temporary tables are visible only in the current session

Comment: I want to avoid transaction because of the volume of data I manipulate (big insertion of data => undo is too long)

Comment: @Patrice Pezillier - You will need to use _different connections_ for each thread.

Comment: Ah--- there is a lot you can do, avoiding transaction is impossible. There always is a transaction. You can commit after every insert or two, but still atomic operations are part of sql serer.

Comment: Can I create 1 temporary table for each thread with different name ?
I need a store procedure which takes the name of the temporary table in argument... Is it possible ?

Comment: @Patrice - re passing the name of a temp table - you really don't want to do that, since you'd end up having to add dynamic SQL to what already sounds complicated.

Comment: @Patrice Pezillier - You _could_, but only by utilizing dynamic SQL (which is evil and can expose you to SQL Injection attacks). Consider using [Table Value Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx), introduced in SQL Server 2008 or [table variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

So long as the multiple threads are using separate connections (which I really hope they are, otherwise there's probably no benefit to multithreading, or you have a massive race condition hiding in your code), they should all have their own copies of the temp table. You shouldn't have to do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The #TempTable [temporary table](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables) should only be available to the current SQL server session/connection, so if you want each process to have a separate #TempTable, just use separate connections for each.
If that is not feasible, you can use table variables, which are somewhat of a cross between regular tables and variables - like this:

```
DECLARE @TableVar TABLE (
  IDColumn int,
  NameColumn varchar(max))

INSERT INTO @TableVar (IDColumn, NameColumn)
SELECT  ID, Name
FROM    RealTable
WHERE   .....
```

If however, you want all processes to use the one and same table, just name it with double hash (##TempTable) and then it will be accessible globally.

Comment: It seems I answered a wrong question :), edited the response to match